# Excel VBA data validation list type conversion - better method?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with data validation list set for the user to choose from a drop down menu a list of times (formatted as h:mm AM/PM), which is then read in VBA to compare the time to another. The data validation seems to have converted the times to a string, so right now it seems I have to just use a block of code to convert that back to a double through VBA so I can do the comparison.

Is there a better method that I'm missing?

What I'm trying to do is let the user choose a time, then on a table with all the times listed, I run a comparison to find the proper cell and put the info in.

Comment: Questions about code should ideally include code...   There are no "types" in a validation list though - everything is a string.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't really have a question about the code itself (yet). I wanted to see if I'm going about this in a completely retarded manner before I tackled trying to do conversions back and forth

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to work Date type. I Show you as you can convert a string to a date. This way your problem is solved.

```
 Sub teste()
    Dim time As Date
    time = TimeValue("9:00 PM")
End Sub
```